# RCP Add banners to application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I would like to add space for advertisements to the top and bottom of my RCP application window.  Is there a special way of creating these, where I can customize the height of each? I read about the `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`, but it seems to indicate it can only do a top banner.

In other words, what would be the best way of implementing this?